# Ensuring TypeScript unions remain narrow throughout the code

Tags: typescript

I have a flow, in which, rather than adding a number of if statements, I'd like to create an object that holds the required information so when it comes to execution it reads in a more linear fashion. I've created a simple and contrived example of this below.

```js
type ItemOne = {
  type: 'itemOne'
  fn: typeof funcOne
  args: Parameters<typeof funcOne>[0]
}

type ItemTwo = {
  type: 'itemTwo',
  fn: typeof funcTwo
  args: Parameters<typeof funcTwo>[0]
}

type Item = ItemOne | ItemTwo


function funcOne({ name }: { name: string }) {
  console.log(name)
}

function funcTwo({ age }: { age: number }) {
  console.log(age)
}

function createItem(shouldCreateItemOne: boolean): Item {
  if (shouldCreateItemOne) {
    return { type: 'itemOne', fn: funcOne, args: { name: 'Dave' } } as const
  }

  return { type: 'itemTwo', fn: funcTwo, args: { age: 22  } } as const
}


const item = createItem(false) 

item.fn(item.args)
```

When I get around to calling the function `item.fn(item.args)` TypeScript complains `Argument of type '{ name: string; } | { age: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; } & { age: number; }'.` Is there a way I can ensure that TypeScript can keep a narrowed version of `item.args`?

There's also a link the example within the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsDyA7aBeKBvAUFKokAXFAOQCW8yapeUAZiiYRAPb0MCuKAxqhHQCGAJwDmAZxIAFEYIQR4w8QB4W7Lr34A%20ANoAGALo4AvjhwtYVACoB3VlEy58LEhWt3SAGjqNm4Nhz03Dy2rEJiklAywnIKEEqq-upBvKG6hiZmFnCIDpaI-FAAPvkIoWY4KTzA5KwoGnxoABRYUCixUMYkre3yJOLAwuQoop0AlNh0PHXirAA2EAB0c6yiTb0QY5mVwTV1DaEtUIKi0F3Yx6ckKJwIAEbx45P40yizC8urTSeb21V79R4wgggngOQQTXEAAtWJw5gATADCwNBEHB-BId1Y8xBKDGJHBzyg5A4kJhcKRKLBVH4Eyc%20CgwOAnGE9VaLjIlAKNE8DCYDX4vJEEm6bVirgAIoIAG4QUidBWCcRQV4DOimOhMllsgj%20VxcsoeXm%20A52IURUU-EgAJmt%20GMiuVquA2xwzuJVDyQJB1MQTXogjm4k2UDMBsWjCa4eF4jGQA)

Comment: This is the topic of [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); the compiler can't follow "correlated unions" like this.  The recommended approach is described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involves refactoring to generic indexed accesses instead of unions.  If I do that for your code it looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3xOkW). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your time, on answering this question and raising issues within the TS repo. Your suggestion is certainly a solution to the problem. I'd happily accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), where you want the return type to change based on the types of the parameters given:

```
function createItem(shouldCreateItemOne: true): ItemOne;
function createItem(shouldCreateItemOne: false): ItemTwo;
function createItem(shouldCreateItemOne: boolean): Item;
function createItem(shouldCreateItemOne: boolean): Item {
  if (shouldCreateItemOne) {
    return { type: 'itemOne', fn: funcOne, args: { name: 'Dave' } } as const
  }

  return { type: 'itemTwo', fn: funcTwo, args: { age: 22  } } as const
}
```

The last overload is optional if you do not wish to support calls to the function with the general `boolean` type. Using an overload allows TypeScript to deduce the right type for this call:

```
const item = createItem(false)
//    ^? ItemTwo
item.fn(item.args) // okay
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsDyA7aBeKBvAUFKokAXFAOQCW8yapeUAZiiYRAPb0MCuKAxqhHQCGAJwDmAZxIAFEYIQR4w8QB4W7Lr34A+ANoAGALo4AvjhwtYVACoB3VlEy58LEhWt3SAGjqNm4Nhz03Dy2rEJiklAywnIKEEqq-upBvKG6hiZmFnCIDpaI-FAAPvkIoWY4KTzA5KwoGnxoABRYUCixUMYkre3yJOLAwuQoop0AlNh0PHXirAA2EAB0c6yiTb0QY5mVwTV1DaEtUIKi0F3Yx6ckKJwIAEbx45P40yizC8urTSeb21V79R4wgggngOQQTXEAAtWJw5gATADCwNBEHB-GYwk4mxI6LQAG4drwAVAgSCwVRITC4UiURSCmgSPRBHNxDjSqFCf9aoC6WjKdDYQjkeT+QyICQ7qx5iCUGNcVQubseaS+eCqULaaK8RKoFKZYI5Qrck4oOQOBqaSLUTqJqb8MDgJxhPVWi4yJRxV4GEwGvxPMcIt02rFXAARQQANwgpE6ccE4lJM2AdFMdEdztdBH8rk9ZQ8Ad8BzsAZEEmDPxIACYq-hjPHE68BtscE3gGaqHkyTbKczWb8cHnFowmkOy+IxkA)

---

If you have more than two items and need more flexibility, then this may not be the best for you. See [@jcalz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75794155/ensuring-typescript-unions-remain-narrow-throughout-the-code/75794201#comment133700738_75794155) for an alternative using generic indexed access.

---

You can also refactor your Item types into a map:

```
interface ItemMap {
  itemOne: typeof funcOne;
  itemTwo: typeof funcTwo;
}

type Item<K extends keyof ItemMap = keyof ItemMap> = {
  [P in K]: { type: P; fn: ItemMap[P]; args: Parameters<ItemMap[P]>[0] };
}[K];
```

with the `createItem` declaration now looking like

```
function createItem(shouldCreateItemOne: true): Item<"itemOne">;
function createItem(shouldCreateItemOne: false): Item<"itemTwo">;
function createItem(shouldCreateItemOne: boolean): Item;
function createItem(shouldCreateItemOne: boolean): Item {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLYFk4AdkDeAUMssJgPIgQBcyYAnrhAPYzIwCuICVEA3CTKYAKgHcWdRszYduCcS0EBfIkWkp0EDAB4A0sggAPSCAAmAZ2QBrCA1lbseZAF4bdh5hy4AfK8JCANoACmQgyHoAunQE9Ey0yMH8HCB0jt4hkclwUADmFnTBOXAYEJBQFjrpeJk+gQAMkcjKKoFRgkRcPGDALOFdvNQAFLEgJSjKMchjpXQWYFCguc0AlAGkCH0WLAA2EAB0Oyy5QzMQK0SqnfI9fXI8iiPIcLkTUy8JIJwYAEbQq+tkJsQNs9odjkMPhcrgNbuEEFAIHBII4hhYABYsTg7MwAYURyIgjj4UignHOaUwOgARORtHxqT5BLDevCCSjMGjMdi8eyiZRqHR4DsLBS0FTaaIJIzmTdWUC+aiMVicfikRz6YLkD8WLskSAVpTtLLuvKEer+douSreRbiVqdXq4AajRhAcB2NaeWrCfbzoDSIiwJwoOFYho6AByOkYPiRgA0KSF8j4iZy+SmZyjABE4AA3CCR5rFuBWYHzIRXQNlENhuLMKMxxQJpP3BQSNN5AqEZ6vOgAJn7pGUJbLWzAlzURHLYGE2n85t9nOFoouRBj+xgICGG-TFhWQA)

Comment: This solution nearly worked for me, but as soon as I replaced the constant `false` within the call to `createItem`  with a variable, the error returns.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't know how to deal with "correlated [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)" as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  It is the case that if you have a value `item` of type `Item`, you should be able to call `item.fn(item.args)`.  But the compiler cannot see that because the type system is unable to represent the correlation between `item.fn` and `item.args` in the abstract.   If it can [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) `item` to either `ItemOne` or `ItemTwo` it would be fine:

```
declare const item: Item;
if (item.type === "itemOne") {
  item.fn(item.args);
} else {
  item.fn(item.args);
}
```

but with just `Item`, the type of `item.args` is the union `{name: string} | {age: number}` while the type of `item.fn` is the union `((a: {name: string}) => void) | ((a: {age: number}) => void)`, and generally speaking it is not safe to call a union of functions with a union of parameters... wwhat if there were `itemA` and `itemB` both of type `Item`.  You shouldn't call `itemA.fn(itemB.args)`, right?  Well the compiler can't tell the difference between that and what you're trying to do, unfortunately.

---

The recommended approach to dealing with correlated unions is described at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  It involves a refactoring away from unions, and to [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), where the operations are expressed as generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

First you should make a simple "mapping" object type from which you build the more complicated `Item` types:

```
interface ItemMap {
  itemOne: { name: string };
  itemTwo: { age: number }
}
```

Now we can make `Item` a generic *distributive object type* (as coined in ms/TS#47109) as follows:

```
type Item<K extends keyof ItemMap = keyof ItemMap> =
  { [P in K]: {
    type: P,
    fn: (arg: ItemMap[P]) => void;
    args: ItemMap[P]
  } }[K];
```

You can recover your `ItemOne` and `ItemTwo` types if you want:

```
type ItemOne = Item<"itemOne">
type ItemTwo = Item<"itemTwo">;
```

and the type `Item` by itself is equivalent to `ItemOne | ItemTwo` due to the [default generic type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) in the definition.

In some sense we haven't changed anything about your types, but the representation as indexes into a mapped type helps the compiler follow things when we write a *generic* operation:

```
function processItem<K extends keyof ItemMap>(item: Item<K>) {
  const fn = item.fn; 
  // const fn: (arg: ItemMap[K]) => void
  const arg = item.args;
  // const arg: ItemMap[K]
  fn(arg); // okay
}
```

or just

```
function processItem<K extends keyof ItemMap>(item: Item<K>) {
  item.fn(item.args); // okay
}
```

You can see that `item.args` is of generic type `ItemMap[K]`, while `item.fn` is of generic type `(arg: ItemMap[K]) => void`, meaning that the compiler definitely sees that `item.args` is a valid argument to the `item.fn` function.

---

And let's test it out:

```
function createItem(shouldCreateItemOne: boolean): Item {
  if (shouldCreateItemOne) {
    return { type: 'itemOne', fn: funcOne, args: { name: 'Dave' } } as const
  }
  return { type: 'itemTwo', fn: funcTwo, args: { age: 22 } } as const
}
```

This still works because the compiler sees that the return value is a valid `Item`.  And when we call it, we get an `Item` (which is `Item<keyof ItemMap>` which is `ItemOne | ItemTwo`):

```
const item = createItem(false);
```

and finally, we can process the item with our processing function:

```
processItem(item); // okay
// function processItem<keyof ItemMap>(item: Item<keyof ItemMap>): void
```

Note that the type argument `K` is inferred as `keyof ItemMap` because `item` is an `Item<keyof ItemMap>`.  This would still work even if `item` were just an `ItemOne` or an `ItemTwo`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-L4arplYjfC9fCYyzaOxhvGIp4H1VhLXGWkryIYAqwRSZwh8PxDmWah5j9L8MEREBeWMfkr0FTRLGAlBwTQjCsPQgUhW0e5HggZ4EwBQVUXRCQnDgXQiEZCN7WQainheTATBcb45j+AF8UEgIfj6XBQToMk7CAA)